# Just hit 20K. How am I doing?

Tags: discussion

I just hit the 20K mark for the first time and to a large extent it doesn't feel that different than the 3k mark.  Sure, there are a few more privileges I'm being trusted with but I'm more interested in what the community expects of me at this level and where I could be doing better.

I'm a big boy so feel free to be honest and direct with your constructive criticism. If there's something I'm doing well feel free to point it out.  I'm making this question about me but the point is what's best for the community.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this question. Do you seek to just get positive and negative criticism? If yes, I believe you'll have more relevant feedback through the up and down votes and comments. If you still want personal feedback, well... you're great. Thank you for your participation.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko I'm offering a chance to provide guidance without it being point or punitive based.  Maybe over this past year the way I've used my privileges hasn't made any impression on you at all. But if I have I'd like to know. Rep isn't all I care about. Becoming correctly socialized with the experienced group that defines what we're about is important to me as well. The most constructive criticism I've ever had, I had to go ask for. That's what I'm doing here.

Comment: Understandable. Well, my personal feedback on your activity is positive; ChrisF seems to agree. In all cases, if you're at 20K, it's because of your valuable participation to our community; those of the users who do not provide value feel pretty quickly that they are not welcome here, through downvotes and comments, or simply the lack of any response (sometimes, indifference may be much more significant than downvotes.)

Comment: If you have made it this far without a moderator suspending your account or new users cursing you by name (I'm looking at you, @gnat ;-) ) then you are fine.

Comment: Also, welcome to the club. In addition to the casual Fridays that everyone else gets, we keep a stash of whiskey in The Whiteboard's fridge.

Comment: If my opinion worth for something, I have to say that I read carefully all your answers and comments. Not only yours, there're like 10 more members  whom I read carefully too. I have found often your reasoning elocuent and I would like to say that It's based on real experiences. That's good. To speak from the experience whenever is possible. I find (sometimes) your humor sense to be ... how to say it.. little bit acid, but may be It's just me :-). Congrats for the 20K.

Comment: Have you considered applying to be a moderator when voting season comes up again? Not saying you should (reminds me of the classic "only way to move up in engineering is to go into management problem"). but I think it's still worth considering. Overall I think you've been doing awesome (even though I'm just a lurker in these parts) :)

Answer (score 4):

Just keep on doing what you've been doing thus far.

As you can see from the [Trusted User Privileges page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) you can now:

> - Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower
> - Voting to undelete answers except those deleted by a moderator
> - Voting to delete questions with a score of -3 or lower immediately after they are closed
> - Editing tag wikis without needing approval

The first and third of these new abilities will help you help us keep the site clean and tidy, removing questions and answers that don't need to be here.

The second helps with making sure that good content isn't lost - in cases where people have misguidedly deleted it in the past.

As to giving feedback on your behaviour, we (both as users and moderators) are encouraged to deal with problems as soon as possible and not let things fester. That they sometimes do is down is something to acknowledge and see where we can do better, but that's not relevant here. Beyond upvotes and leaving positive comments there are no other mechanisms for giving positive feedback.

If you were doing things wrong you would have heard about it by now. However, it does mean that if you are doing OK to great you don't get to hear about it, you just see a steady increase in reputation.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at my reputation, you´ll come to the point that im either not really good at software development, or not long enough at it - no matter what is the case, there are things I am good at.

For me there is only one thing I am looking for: Does what I´m doing meet my requirements? If so I am satisfied, if not I try to reach the next level. Because of some bad experiences I´ve learned, that this is the most important thing, because you´ll never know what people really think of you and (more important) why.

I think there are much more important things than gaining reputation (I am the perfect person to tell you that though ;) ) Being polite, helpful to new users or beginners and always curios about the thoughts of other people would meet my expectations. No matter what reputation you have. But your question shows me, that youre on the right way for my expecations.

And one more thing, to take a little deepness from my post: If it was your childhood-dream to reach 20K rep at SE-Software Engineering: Well done mate, you got it! Enjoy your success and if you´ve finished enjoying watch out for the next site to reach 20k rep (https://stackexchange.com/sites#) ;))

Comment: *“9 questions, 13 answers [...] and 20k reputation”*: you're looking at the stats on Meta. The reputation comes from questions and answers on the actual SoftwareEngineering.SE website, where CandiedOrange has, at the moment of writing, 350 answers.

Comment: Hmmm... Looks like I really got it ;)) Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure your success over time, may I suggest you look at your "average score per post"? That might give you a more accurate impression on how the community values your contributions. For example, mine is currently around 64, which is not very high compared with the other >50K users.

Comment: sounds like a good idea, do I need to build a query for that?

Comment: @CandiedOrange I just looked at my user profile: 27,290 divided by (326 answers + 4 questions = 330 posts) = 82.7 average score per post.

Comment: Use math!?! ;) BTW questions need a different weight. They're only 5 points per up vote.

Comment: well the Hot Network Questions _really_ makes score per post a difficult metric...

Comment: @enderland yeah I'd be more interested in this number once it's divided by total views.

Comment: @DocBrown, If this metric does not rate you highly then it is not a good metric!

Comment: @dan1111: thanks ;-) I think that metrics does rate me high enough, and the ones who are getting a higher score are deserving it.

Answer (score 1):

By reading your question I cannot tell whether you are insecure or really vain. Maybe both. From your answers I can tell you are are entertaining, you like to interact and you know your stuff.

You may want to stop and stand and ask yourself what the site is doing to you as a person. I mean, really, acknowledgement is nice, but soliciting for judgement by strangers in a more direct manner than getting points, why?

Personally I find myself spending way too much time here and I notice the site is turning me into a nazi. The more power I get, the more I feel like exercising it and I have become one of those people I hated when I just joined.

Answer (score 0):

Well I just started my journey, I might feel like getting an Olympic medal if I reach 20k :P, Amazing contribution bro... have less reputation to add comment, so I m writing this post as an answer.